# Finding the unit of Pressure/Volume

Tags: mathematical-physics, units, si-units

Me and my friend are trying to find the exact unit of **Power=Pressure/Volume**. We know that the unit has to be W(J/s) so we try from the equation above:
(Kg*m²/s³)=(N/A)/V
The right side will be:
(Kg*m/s²)/m^5
Then,
Kg/(s²*m⁴)
So at the end:
(Kg*m²/s³) ≠ Kg/(s²*m⁴).
Are we missing something?

We know we can get the exact unit using:
W=F×x ==> F=W/x
And etc...
But we want to know why the first way is wrong?
[The example we are trying to solve](https://d.top4top.net/p_1056di5p60.jpg)

Comment: power$\ne$pressure/volume but work = pressure $\times$ volume

Comment: Even if we say that W=P/V. (Kg*m²/s²) = (N/A)/V... The final result will be the same as above, the m⁴ wil still down

Comment: Malwarebytes blocks the website in your link for me. As @Farcher says, you can't get this to work out, because "Power = pressure/volume" is just plain wrong.

Comment: Power=Pressure/Volume is wrong, and you have taken W=P/V as argument in your comment,whereas it should be W=P*V.

Comment: Oh, I see! Our doctoe told us something like a relation between Power and pressure over volume and in his slides (the one that he have) the relation is wrong. Thank you all for the answer.

Comment: @GalaxyLimits "something like.." usually isn't good enough for doing science. "Nearly right" actually means "wrong".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Power=Pressure/Volume** is an incorrect relation.

To put it simple :Power is defined as "Rate of doing 
work"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(physics)

Which means,the dimension of power is J/s or (Kg*m^2/(s^2)).

Whereas the dimension of Pressure/Volume is Kg/(s^2*m^4)).

The first method is wrong because, Power=Pressure/Volume is just plain wrong. No such relation exists.

Comment: Or you could say that,power has units of Pressure*Volume/time which is not equal to the unit of pressure/volume. So Power is not equal to Pressure/volume.